# If we find all cosets that are also groups of a group, does this describe all subgroups of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are all subgroups of a group also cosets of the group. E.g. do the cosets that end up being groups themselves describe all subgroups of a group?

Comment: Isomorphism is talked about between two groups, not between a coset and and another set.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Sorry, I have rephrased it, this is what I meant. I am not comfortable with the use of isomorphic yet, but it seemed right. Apologies

Comment: Only one coset is a group!

Comment: @mich95 Truly?${}$

Answer (score 5):

Let G be a finite group (for simplicity) and H a subgroup of index k>1. Then there are k distinct left cosets of H in G one of which is 1H=H. Hence H is a (sub)group of G. Since the cosets partiton G, no other coset than H contains the idendity, and hence no other coset is a subgroup of G.

Comment: Take a coset of $\Bbb Z / 8 \Bbb Z$?

Comment: When one says cosets, we need two things : a group G and a subgroup H of G!

Comment: Well since $H\leq G=\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$, we can take $H=G$ and then we have the cosets $1H,3H,5H,7H$? These are all equivalent to $G$ right? So we have $4$ cosets that are a group?

Comment: @Understand If you take $H=G$, then the index is $1$...

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a really intuitive group, $\Bbb R^3$ under vector addition.

Now, let's pick a subgroup $H$; my personal favorite is the $xy$-plane; the set of all vectors of the form $H = \{(x,y,0) : x,y \in \Bbb R\}$.

Now the cosets of $H$ are *literally* the translates of $H$; for any vector $v = (x', y',z') \in \Bbb R^3$, we get the coset $v + H = \{v + h: h \in H\}$, which consists of all vectors of the form $(x, y, z')$, where $x$ and $y$ can be arbitrary, but the $z$-coordinate is that of our fixed $v$.

These vectors are not a subspace (hence subgroup) of $\Bbb R^3$, whenever $z' \neq 0$; that is, whenever $v \not\in H$.

This same kind of reasoning applies to all cosets of all groups: cosets of a subgroup are a kind of "translate" of that subgroup, and are not themselves groups except when the coset *is* the subgroup; when we've used the identity translation (translating by something in the subgroup, which leaves our coset fixed).

So, in a very trivial way, every subgroup is a coset: but only of itself, and only in the "boring" way, where the translation doesn't actually do anything!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $G$ is a group, $H < G$ is a subgroup, and $C = gH$ is a (left) coset. Let $e \in G$ be the unique identity element. Of course every group contains an identity element. So, does $C$ contain the identity element $e$? We have:

$$e \in C \iff e \in gH \iff g^{-1} \in H \iff g \in H \iff gH = H \iff C = H
$$

Therefore, $C$ is a subgroup if and only if $C=H$.

The exact same proof, with symbols in different positions, words for right cosets.

So yes, the only cosets that are groups are also subgroups.